# How to change link to document in Umbraco manually

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

My breadcrumbs are broken because of incorrect link to home page.
Please tell me, how can I change the "Link to document" parameter manually.
I use umbraco 4.7.2
I need the omain name only on home page and full absolute pathes on internal pages.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Right Click on on Home Content and select Manage Hosting.

[image]

Enter Domain Name and select Language  and click on Add New Domain / Update button.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your "link to document" field is set to "/" which from your question sounds like what you wanted? If not you have a few options.

Check out these settings that you can use for giving a page an alternative url or name:

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracourlname

One of those might best suit your issue. umbracoUrlAlias allows you to pick a different url that can be used to render the same page (handy for correcting incorrect urls).

I'd highly recommend installing the 301 redirect package to avoid some of these issues in the future: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-url-tracker

Cheers

Pete